# Un-italicising entire row of matrix

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, matrices

I've got a matrix like:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{15}
\begin{document}
$\begin{bmatrix}
I & L & i & k & e & t & h & e & H & P & P & R & I & M & E \\
8 & 11 & 8 & 10 & 4 & 19 & 7 & 4 & 7 & 15 & 15 & 17 & 8 & 12 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$
\end{document}
```

I want to un italicise the entire first row without making it messy using the `\text{}` command for every single cell.
How would I go about doing this??
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I've taken the liberty of making your code minimally compilable. Feel free to revert.

Comment: Do you plan to have (sub)matrices or other complex objects in the first row?

Comment: Thank you @Mico

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is quite simple with `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath} 

\begin{document}
It is quite simple with \texttt{+bmatrix} adding \texttt{mode=text} option for the first row:
\[\begin{+bmatrix}[row{1}={mode=text}]
I & L & i & k & e & t & h & e & H & P & P & R & I & M & E \\
8 & 11 & 8 & 10 & 4 & 19 & 7 & 4 & 7 & 15 & 15 & 17 & 8 & 12 & 4
\end{+bmatrix}\]
The following example is just to show that the other rows are in math mode:
\[\begin{+bmatrix}[row{1}={mode=text}]
I & L & i & k & e & t & h & e & H & P & P & R & I & M & E \\
\alpha & \beta & \gamma & 10 & 4 & 19 & 7 & 4 & 7 & 15 & 15 & 17 & 8 & 12 & 4\\
a^2 & \sqrt{b} & \frac{c}{d} & 10 & 4 & 19 & 7 & 4 & 7 & 15 & 15 & 17 & 8 & 12 & 4
\end{+bmatrix}\]

Note that in the examples above the space between rows is a little larger than in an ordinary \texttt{bmatrix}. 
If you don't like it, you can set \texttt{rowsep=0pt} to have the same row separator as an ordinary \texttt{bmatrix}:
\[\begin{+bmatrix}[row{1}={mode=text}, rowsep=0pt]
I & L & i & k & e & t & h & e & H & P & P & R & I & M & E \\
8 & 11 & 8 & 10 & 4 & 19 & 7 & 4 & 7 & 15 & 15 & 17 & 8 & 12 & 4
\end{+bmatrix}\]
The following example is just to show that the other rows are in math mode:
\[\begin{+bmatrix}[row{1}={mode=text}, rowsep=0pt]
I & L & i & k & e & t & h & e & H & P & P & R & I & M & E \\
\alpha & \beta & \gamma & 10 & 4 & 19 & 7 & 4 & 7 & 15 & 15 & 17 & 8 & 12 & 4\\
a^2 & \sqrt{b} & \frac{c}{d} & 10 & 4 & 19 & 7 & 4 & 7 & 15 & 15 & 17 & 8 & 12 & 4
\end{+bmatrix}\]

The following examples are with an ordinary \texttt{bmatrix}, just to compare with the previous ones:\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{15}
\[\begin{bmatrix}
I & L & i & k & e & t & h & e & H & P & P & R & I & M & E \\
8 & 11 & 8 & 10 & 4 & 19 & 7 & 4 & 7 & 15 & 15 & 17 & 8 & 12 & 4
\end{bmatrix}\]
The following example is just to show that all the rows are in math mode with an ordinary \texttt{bmatrix}:
\[\begin{bmatrix}
I & L & i & k & e & t & h & e & H & P & P & R & I & M & E \\
\alpha & \beta & \gamma & 10 & 4 & 19 & 7 & 4 & 7 & 15 & 15 & 17 & 8 & 12 & 4\\
a^2 & \sqrt{b} & \frac{c}{d} & 10 & 4 & 19 & 7 & 4 & 7 & 15 & 15 & 17 & 8 & 12 & 4
\end{bmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would tend to prefer `\SetRow` over `row{1}=` if only because it keeps the formatting override more closely tied to the row that it corresponds to. In general, I only recommend using the `row{}=` syntax as part of a tblr format (and then only for the first/last rows).

Comment: @DonHosek I prefer `row{1}=` because it leaves the style separated from the content. Since it is for the first line, there is no problem (you don't have to count the lines). However, both solutions work, so it's a matter of taste.

Comment: The way I solved it at first was to use ChatGPT to put every letter inside a \text{}. It was messy and chunky, but it worked. However, @CarLaTeX's solution is far better. Thank you everyone!!

Comment: @LambSauce You're welcome and thank you for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 3):

(simplified the answer a bit)

You may achieve your formatting objective by (a) using a fixed-width column type instead of the `c` column type that underlies the `bmatrix` environment and (b) encasing the first row in a `tabular` environment and the second row in an `array` environment, using the same fixed-width column type for both.

Note that because all cells have the same fixed width (given, most easily, as the width of a two-digit number), the overall `bmatrix` is a bit wider than before. Note that I've also equated `\tabcolsep` with `\arraycolsep`, so that the amount of intercolumn whitespace is the same for both environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'bmatrix' env. and 'MaxMatrixCols' counter
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{15} % just for this example

\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\usepackage{calc}  % for '\widthof' macro
\newcolumntype{U}{wc{\widthof{19}}} % fixed-width column type
\setlength\tabcolsep\arraycolsep % 5pt instead of '6pt'

\newcommand\RowA{I & L & i & k & e & t & h & e & H & P & P & R & I & M & E}
\newcommand\RowB{8 & 11 & 8 & 10 & 4 & 19 & 7 & 4 & 7 & 15 & 15 & 17 & 8 & 12 & 4}

\begin{document}

%% "before"
$\begin{bmatrix}
  \RowA \\
  \RowB
\end{bmatrix}$

\smallskip

%% "after"
$\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{tabular}{@{} *{15}{U} @{}}
  \RowA 
\end{tabular} \\
\begin{array}{@{} *{15}{U} @{}}
  \RowB
\end{array}
\end{bmatrix}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: But this is cheating.  It overrides the desire to use math mode.  It would be more direct to simply wrap `\[ \left[...\right] \]` around the `tabular` and forget about the `bmatrix`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I still need a way to create a line break between the `tabular` row vector and the `array` row vector. `\[ \left[ \begin{tabular}{...} ... \end{tabular} \\ \begin{array}{...} ... \end{array} \right] \]` doesn't create the needed line break.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tested it and it works - in case anyone is wondering on my end. As a result, your solution is a viable answer

Answer (score 1):

You could always write:

```
$\mathrm{
    \begin{bmatrix}
      …
    \end{bmatrix}
 }$
```

assuming that you don’t have any non-italic inside your matrix.

---

**note**: this doesn’t actually work because the math of the individual cells of a matrix are actually math inside of a box inside the math so the math font will be reset. I knew that, but forgot momentarily.

Comment: `\mathrm` doesn't "peer" inside the contents of a `bmatrix`.

Comment: Did you actually try this?  I did, and it had no effect.

Comment: It doesn't work, but if it did, it would un-italicise the whole matrix, not just the first row.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I never try my stuff, natch.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Except the original proposal had only numbers in the second row, which are set non-italic by default.

Comment: @DonHosek Sorry but I still think your answer is actually and conceptually wrong